# "A lot of nature " ....can I say it this way?

Tags: vocabulary

How can I use the word nature when I want to describe different places with different nature?.Can I say

> I like living in a place with A LOT OF NATURE.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatical, but it's not clear what you mean by it. You really need to spell it out with something like:

> I like living in a place with lots of natural features, such as
>   forests, lakes and mountains.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a *green place* that you like living in.

> I like living in a green place.

Comment: It could be green, but not spectacular with mountains and rivers